# Oracle loop through CLOB to get string

Tags: oracle, substr, clob

I want to convert all data in CLOB to string. DBMC_LOB.SUBSTR provides a way to fetch 4000 characters at once. I am from MS SQL background and not aware of Oracle queries. Can someone help me with the syntax.

I want to make a function and do something like

```
// Get the length of CLOB
// totalIterationsRequired = length/4000;
// LOOP around the CLOB and fetch 4000 char at once 
For i in 1..totalIterationsRequired
LOOP
// Insert the substring into a varchar2
//  DBMC_LOB.SUBSTR(xml_value,4000*i,(4000*(i-1)+1)
END LOOP
// The function will return the varchar2
```

Comment: Please ask your question. Thanks.

Comment: I need help with syntax. Updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
create table save_table(rec varchar2(4000));

create or replace PROCEDURE save_clob (p_clob IN CLOB)
AS
    l_length             INTEGER;
    l_start              INTEGER := 1;
    l_recsize   CONSTANT INTEGER := 4000;
BEGIN
    l_length   := DBMS_LOB.getlength (p_clob);

    WHILE l_start <= l_length
    LOOP
        INSERT INTO save_table (rec)
             VALUES (DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR (p_clob, l_recsize, l_start));

        l_start   := l_start + l_recsize;
    END LOOP;
END save_clob;
```

Comment: I think it would give an error on save_table. And where are we adding the string to save)clob which is being returned?

Comment: This code does work, it was extracted from an existing package. In this example we are saving the results to a table called 'SAVE_TABLE'. You would then select the results out of the table. It is not a function. A PL/SQL function can only return 32767 characters, a SQL function 4000 (by default, the database can be configured to a larger value). The reason to use a CLOB is that the contents don't fit within a string. What would you do if the CLOB size is too big?

Comment: You are correct but this doesnt compile. I think there is something wrong in the syntax

Comment: I resolved the compile issues but how to select the table?

Comment: I don't understand your question *how to select the table*.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the function definition

```
create or replace function getclobastable (id IN VARCHAR2) 
  return clob_table
is
    l_length             INTEGER;
    l_start              INTEGER := 1;
    l_recsize   CONSTANT INTEGER := 4000;
    i_clob                 CLOB;
    n BINARY_INTEGER := 0;
    save_table clob_table := clob_table();
BEGIN

    save_table := clob_table();
    -- Get the CLOB data into i_clob
    l_length := DBMS_LOB.getlength (i_clob);

    WHILE l_start <= l_length
    LOOP
        n := n + 1;

        save_table.EXTEND();
        save_table(n) := DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR (i_clob, l_recsize, l_start);

        l_start   := l_start + l_recsize;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN save_table;
END;
```